# Can i modify files on Git server post-receive hook

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to know if it is possible to change pushed files with git server side "post-receive" hook ?

Comment: Changing files would basicly change the commit hashes and break git, its better to do it client side in the pre-commit hook

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.